# Migrating Laserfiche to Alfresco

Tags: migration, document-management, alfresco

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laserfiche migration to Alfresco](https://serverfault.com/questions/288437/laserfiche-migration-to-alfresco)

There has been some discussion of how to **migrate a Laserfiche repository to Alfresco**. Has anyone successfully done so, and what was your method?

Keep in mind the repository in question is ~100 terabytes in size, and used by 100's of users.

Answer (score 1):

In the previous question, the OP stated that there's a LF toolkit available for about $2400; sounds like that's the way to go for trying to migrate data from a proprietary repository.